# PSCP in exec/shell_exec PHP

Tags: php, ajax, exec, sftp, shell-exec

I'm trying to send files from one server to other using SFTP comunication.

SO Server From: Windows Server
SO Server To: I dont know :(

To do this i only need to run:

```
pscp -i "MY_SSH_KEY.ppk"  MY_FILE USER_FTP@URL_SERVER_TO_SEND:/PATH/TO/SEND
```

Situations that works fine:

1. Run this command from CMD in windows;
2. Put this command in exec function in a PHP file and call this PHP file using cmd;
   Conde in PHP file:

```
<?php
$command = 'pscp -i "MY_SSH_KEY.ppk"  MY_FILE USER_FTP@URL_SERVER_TO_SEND:/PATH/TO/SEND && echo success || echo error';
$result = "";

exec($command,$result);
echo json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

But, if i call that same PHP file from my front, using ajax, it doesn't work.

NOTE: To call this PHP file from cmd, i use this command:

```
php NAME_MY_FILE.php
```

Many thanks guys!

Comment: Probably need full paths for one or more things `c:\path\to\pscp` and maybe for the `ppk`.

Comment: "it doesn't work" Please [edit] your question to describe what specifically happens when you run your code. Do you get error messages? What do they say?

Comment: Do not use pscp, use PHP SSH library instead, like phpseclib or PHP SSH2 module.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved,

When I run de php using CMD of windows, everything works fine because the CMD runs the commands using administrator user. When I call it by the website, the PHP runs the exec using system user which hasn’t permission to run the PSCP command.

When I gave PHP service permission to run as administrator, the execution works.